# Swift: Filter a dictionary key from a struct from an array, which is optional

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, struct, option-type

```
struct Test {
    var title: String
    var message: [String?: String?]

    init(title: String, message: [String?:String?]) {
        self.title = title
        self.message = message
    }
}

var cases = [
     Test(title: "1", message: ["tag1": nil]),
     Test(title: "2", message: ["tag2": "preview2"]),
     Test(title: "3", message: [nil:nil]),
     Test(title: "4", message: ["tag1":"preview4"])
]
```

Now, I want:

1. An array with all keys from message property from cases - tag1 and tag2 (no nils in it). I just tried everything I know, I couldn't do it. Tried with filtering cases, got optionals.
2. There are no previews without a tag, so there is no need for an array with them. I only need a list with the tags, in order to sort it and show the relevant previews from the cases. That's why I need to know a way how to access these previews from the cases. Let's say in a UITableView:

   ```
   cell.previewLabel?.text = cases[indexPath.row].preview[//No idea what here]
   ```

Of course, a dictionary with `[tags: previews]` would also be perfect!

Thanks in advance! I hope what I want is possible.

Comment: For #1, it would be very helpful to provide the specific output you would expect given your input. Would the result be `["preview2", "preview4"]`? or something else? If there were also a `["tag3": "preview3"]`, would you want it included, or not? If there are no previews without tags, why is `message` defined as `[String?:String?]` rather than `[String:String]?`? Similarly, it feels like there is only exactly one key and one value or no keys and no values. Why a dictionary? Why not a `struct Message { var key, value: String}` and then use `Message?`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not completely clear to me what you're attempting to do, however, this will filter your `cases` array to only `Test` objects that contain non-nil `values` in the message dictionary:

```
let nonNil = cases.filter { (test) -> Bool in
    return Array(test.message.values).filter({ (value) -> Bool in
        return value == nil
    }).count <= 0
}
```

The variable `nonNil` now contains the `Test` objects where title is "2" and title is "4".

You could further filter that if you want a `[tags:preview]` dictionary. Something like this would do that:

```
let tags = nonNil.map( { $0.message} ).flatMap { $0 }.reduce([String:String]()) { (accumulator, current) -> [String:String] in
    guard let key = current.key, let value = current.value else { return accumulator }
    var accum = accumulator
    accum.updateValue(value, forKey: key)
    return accum
}
```

The `tags` dictionary now contains: `["tag1": "preview4", "tag2": "preview2"]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an array that only contains elements from `cases` that have all keys and values not `nil` :

```
let filtered = cases.filter { test in
    return test.message.allSatisfy({ entry in
        return entry.key != nil && entry.value != nil
    })
}
```

Or using the shorthand notation :

```
let filtered = cases.filter {
    $0.message.allSatisfy({
        $0.key != nil && $0.value != nil
    })
}
```

---

With structs there is a default initializer, so you can write your `Test` struct this way:

```
struct Test {
    var title: String
    var message: [String?: String?]
}
```